# How to efficiently add developer metadata to sheets' row/column ranges?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, metadata

I am trying to add developer metadata to certain row ranges with Google Apps Script. So far I cobbled together this piece of code:

```
function updateMetadata() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("<sheet id>");
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var productNameRanges = dataRange.getMergedRanges();
  productNameRanges.forEach(function(productRange){
    var productName = productRange.getCell(1, 1).getValue();
    for (var j=productRange.getRow(); j<=productRange.getLastRow(); j++){
      var range = sheet.getRange(j+":"+j);
      // Remove old metadata
      range.getDeveloperMetadata().forEach(function(md){
        md.remove();
      });
      // Add new metadata
      range.addDeveloperMetadata(
        "product_name", 
        productName, 
        SpreadsheetApp.DeveloperMetadataVisibility.PROJECT
      );
    }
  });
}
```

The purpose of this was supposed to be to mark merged cell ranges with a metadata value to make it possible to retrieve those ranges by the merged cells' value. So far though, the function never terminates, the last execution duration that is shown is around 8 seconds. The metadata still gets modified though, but I never checked if it was for all the ranges.

Is there any other (efficient, or right at all) way to achieve this with apps script? Can I maybe somehow mark row ranges with a single method call instead of iterating over rows (it is not possible according to error messages I get when I am trying to)?

Comment: You only need to mark (with meta-data) the top-left most cell in a merged range. The other cells in a merged range are typically inaccessible.

Comment: Yeah, didn't even think of that because I wanted to get all rows by metadata in one request. And what's worse, it still took 40 seconds for my modest 128 row table. At least it terminates now.

Comment: Do not merge cells. Do not workaround merged cells. It'll cause multiple problems down the road.

Comment: @TheMaster I'm afraid I need my app to work with them. I considered using firebase instead but it would be an overkill. I have some 8 merged cell ranges and even if I add metadata to only their first rows, it takes 40 seconds. I can't imagine what can be happening behind the scenes to cause this. Even if it did an sql update per row per metadata addition, it is still way too much.

Comment: @TheMaster is there any wisdom you could impart on why are merged cells such a problem?

Comment: @Ivan If there's one thing in spreadsheets, which if you avoid, will save you a lot of pain: it's merged cells. Ask any spreadsheet expert or forum and they'll agree on this. If merged cells are necessary for your spreadsheet, you're designing it wrong. As to why-  basically it creates chaos. None of the other modifications to the sheet are as damaging as merging cells: There's a specific order of rows and columns, which is foundational to the spreadsheet and almost all scripts/formulas depend on this integrity and merging destroys that integrity.

Comment: Having said that, you can use *sheets api through advanced Google services* in apps script to set developer data much much faster.  To say again, If you're doing this to workaround merged cells limitations, you're building on a shaky foundation.

Comment: @TheMaster Thanks for the advice. Using spreadsheet gapi this way seems promising; as for merged cells they are more of a header deal to group actual data rows so they will not be used in formulas etc.

Comment: @TheMaster, please consider posting your pieces of advice as a community answer, so it can be documented for future uses that have similar doubts.

Comment: @alberto Added as a answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Merging cells and working with merged cells are never recommended.
- For better performance, consider using [sheets api](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/metadata) through [advanced google services or direct https request to the api end point through urlfetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)